# Real Time Analysis of Large Number of Data Points Provided by a Web Service

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, architecture

The story. I have a Java based Web service client running pulling data that ‘can be’ updated every 60 seconds 24*7*365.

There are 1,000 + data points which I need to monitor if a new update is available in real time.  If a new data point is available I need to append the new value in a MySQl database.

I then need to analyse/display the data in Graphical form within a java based web-app ASAP.

Does anyone have any advice as to efficient software architecture? Specifically:

- Database Schema, Single big table Vs Many small tables
- Database Appends, would I need to implement some form of multi-threading to optimize performance?
- What is the best trigger mechanism to calculate & push updates to the web-app?

Any advice/ constructive criticism is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a huge amount of data / rapid change. i.e. storing the input values in memory is not a big overhead. Although you've not said what's involved in capturing the data points - if it takes 1 second to capture each one, then running it in a single thread you're not going to be able to iterate through the set in 60 seconds: you'll need to look at multi-threading.

If you've got control over the code which prepares the inputs for the processing, then it's worth considering implementing the processing within the same executable - but do think about locking. Running the collation from a cron job at this frequency is about borderline - there are a number of constraints which vary depending on the implementation of cron - and you need to think about what happens if a single invocation takes longer than the actual interval to process - if it were me I'd do it in the data capture or running as a daemon.

> Database Schema, Single big table Vs Many small tables

The answer is that a single table is usually preferable to multiple tables - certainly it's preferable to 1000 tables!

> Database Appends, would I need to implement some form of multi-threading to optimize performance?

Only if you are really creating/updating 1000 rows on every invocation and MUST have real-time response below around 10ms tolerance.

> What is the best trigger mechanism to calculate & push updates to the web-app?

This is too vague to give any sensible answer.

> display the data in Graphical form

Again its a very vague question - is the output a single boolean? A set of ordinal values? Something else?

This [javascript plotter](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/) might be useful.